# É possível reverter as alterações de apenas um arquivo de um commit?

Tags: git, commit

Suponhamos que foi feito um `commit` e que um arquivo foi modificado erroneamente. Existe alguma forma de reverter esse `commit` apenas para o arquivo que se deseja?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, existem 2 formas de fazer isso:

1- Especificando o número da revisão do commit do arquivo:

```
git checkout revisao nomedoarquivo
```

2- Especificando o número de revisões que você deseja reverter o arquivo (número de revisões revertidas depois do ~):

```
git checkout master~1 nomedoarquivo
```

Para maiores informações, olha a [referência](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Comment: Obrigado .. :-D